# iTask - how to use variables as parameters to TTask procedure

Tags: multithreading, delphi, task

I need to create a number of iTasks that will populate the same array in different positions. Since the code to be performed for each Task is the same, I decided to create an array of iTasks and created 4 tasks.  I got a problem when passing parameters to the major procedure inside the iTask. when I use variables as parameters , only the values of the last Task created are being considered.  When I pass the parameters as values (hard-coded) it respect all values for each task.  Please see my code :

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  UNTThreads, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Threading ;

type
 Vet         = array of integer;

type
  TFMThreadArray = class(TForm)
    EDTArraySize: TEdit;
    EDTNumberofThreads: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    LBArraySize: TLabel;
    LBThreads: TLabel;
    BTUsingForLoop: TButton;
    EDTThread: TEdit;
    BTHardCoded: TButton;

    procedure BTUsingForLoopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BTHardCodedClick(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }


    procedure  ProcA ( Const  pin, pfin, Psize, Ptask  : integer;
                       Var   Parray : vet);

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FMThreadArray: TFMThreadArray;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


// Procedure to be called by each iTask    
    procedure TFMThreadArray.ProcA ( Const  pin, pfin, Psize, Ptask  : integer;
                                      Var   Parray : vet);
    var
        vind : integer;

    begin
          for vind := pin to pfin do
          begin
               Parray[vind]   := vind * 10;
          end;
    end;
```

==> This below method,  BTHardCodedClick, produces the expected result.  It populates the array accordingly. BUT it is hard coded in creating 4 iTasks and in passing parameters in ProcA. I don't want to implement this way !

```
procedure TFMThreadArray.BTHardCodedClick(Sender: TObject);

var
    varray                   : vet;
    ind, indtask             : Integer;
    Ptasks                   : array of iTask;

begin
     memo1.Clear;

     SetLength(PTasks,Strtoint(EDTNumberofThreads.text));
     SetLength(varray,StrToint(EDTarraysize.text));

     // fill array with a initial value -2
     for ind := Low(varray) to High(varray) do
            varray[ind] :=-2;


     // when call ProcA passing values parameters it works propperly
     PTasks[0] := TTask.Create( procedure
                                      begin
                                             ProcA(0,3,16,0,varray) ;
                                      end
                                     ) ;

     PTasks[1] := TTask.Create( procedure
                                      begin
                                             ProcA(4,7,16,1,varray) ;
                                      end
                                     ) ;

     PTasks[2] := TTask.Create( procedure
                                      begin
                                             ProcA(8,11,16,2,varray) ;
                                      end
                                     ) ;

     PTasks[3] := TTask.Create( procedure
                                      begin
                                             ProcA(12,15,16,3,varray) ;
                                      end
                                     ) ;


     for Indtask := Low(Ptasks) to High(Ptasks) do
         Ptasks[Indtask].Start;

     TTask.WaitForAll(Ptasks);

     memo1.Clear;
     memo1.Lines.Add(' ============== Creating TASKs with hard-coded parameters ===============');
     memo1.lines.add(' Array size : '        + EDTArraySize.text +
                      ' number of Tasks : ' + EDTNumberofThreads.text);
     memo1.Lines.Add(' =========================================================');

     for ind := Low(varray) to High(varray) do
          memo1.Lines.Add(' Array position  : '    + Format('%.3d',[ind])  +
                          '   content  : ' + varray[ind].ToString   );

end;
```

[image]

===>  The following method is the one I want to implement BUT it is not working !, because it is not populating the array.  It seems that only the last iTask " PTasks[indtask]" is being performed.

```
procedure TFMThreadArray.BTUsingForLoopClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    varray                           : vet;
    Ptasks                           : array of iTask;
    vind, indtask, vslice            : Integer;
    vfirst, vlast, vthreads, vsize   : Integer;

begin

     vthreads := Strtoint(EDTNumberofThreads.text);
     vsize    := StrToint(EDTArraysize.text);

     SetLength(PTasks,vthreads);
     SetLength(varray,vsize);

     for vind := Low(varray) to High(varray) do
            varray[vind]:=-33;

     vslice := Length(varray) div vthreads;


     for indtask := Low(PTasks) to High(PTasks) do
     begin
          vfirst := indtask       * vslice;
          vlast  := (indtask + 1) * vslice - 1;

          if (Length(varray) mod vthreads <> 0) and (indtask = High(Ptasks)) then
               vlast := HIgh(varray);

          PTasks[indtask] := TTask.Create( procedure
                                            begin
                                                  procA(vfirst,vlast,vsize,indtask,varray) ;
                                            end
                                           ) ;
     end;

     // Starting all Tasks
     for Indtask := Low(Ptasks) to High(Ptasks) do
         Ptasks[Indtask].Start;

     // Waits until all Tasks been concluded
     TTask.WaitForAll(Ptasks);

     memo1.Clear;
     memo1.Lines.Add(' =============  Using For Loop to create the TASKs =====================');
     memo1.lines.add(' Array size : '        + EDTArraySize.text +
                      ' number of Tasks : ' + EDTNumberofThreads.text);
     memo1.Lines.Add(' =========================================================');


     for vind := Low(varray) to High(varray) do
         memo1.Lines.Add(' Array position  : '    + Format('%.3d',[vind])  +
                         '   content  : '         + varray[vind].ToString   );

end;

end.
```

[image]
I can't understand why a call to procA(vfirst,vlast,vsize,indtask,varray) inside the iTask  is not considering the values of parameters vfirst, vlast. 
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Try removing 'const' from procA. I don't know for sure if it will work, but I suspect it will. A lot goes on behind the scenes with const and one of the bad situations is when you modify a 'const' parameter during the lifetime of the call, which is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @Dsm removing const will not help. See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

The effect you are observing is due to anonymous method variable capture mechanism. It does not capture variable values at specific point during code execution, but location of the variables.

Since all tasks run after the loop where you create them, you will see only the last value stored.

To solve your problem you have to add additional function ensuring that you don't capture common variables in your task.

```
function CreateTask(vfirst, vlast, vsize, indtask: integer; var varray: Vet): ITask;
var
  va: Vet;
begin
  // var parameter cannot be captured so we have to store it into
  // local variable - dynamic arrays act like pointers and any changes
  // to local variable will actually change the original too        
  va := varray;
  Result := TTask.Create(
        procedure
        begin
          ProcA(vfirst, vlast, vsize, indtask, va);
        end);
end;
```

And then you call it like

```
  Ptasks[indtask] := CreateTask(vfirst, vlast, vsize, indtask, varray);
```

Of course, you can also remove your `ProcA` procedure and incorporate its logic directly inside `CreateTask` function if that suits your needs.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for the help and the explanation! I implemented this function as you proposed and it worked as I expected.  Great help from you !

Comment: thre is another point I forgot to mention : in addition to variable va : vet , in fact I have a record   myrec = record    va : vet;  f1 : integer;  f2 : integer; end; I understood and I checked that for va filed which is a dynamic array, the procedure inside TTask updates its values accordingly,  BUT for fields f1 and f2 , TTask update them but at the end , in the caller procedure, those fields are empty !!  It does not work !  Could you tell me why ??

Comment: Dynamic array is reference type - that means no matter how much you assign it from one variable to another - you will always operate on same array content. On the other hand records are value types - when you assign one to another - its content will be copied and original will not be changed. It is hard to say how to solve your problem without exact code. Probably you should use class instead of record. But you also have another issue here. While you have divided your array in parts that can be safely manipulated from multiple threads - changing shared integer fields is not thread safe.

Comment: You should probably ask another question for that.

Comment: thanks!  I'll post another question with code as example !  I'll coount on our help again, if possible !

Comment: I opened another question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292602/itask-values-parameters-to-anonymous-procedure] I appreciate if you can check that ! Thanks!