# iTask - values parameters to anonymous procedure

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I need to create a certain number of iTasks to perform operations in a dynamic array and other fields in a record. Each iTask operates in a specific portion of this array. The array is a field in a record which is passed as a var parameter to the iTask.

The operations in the array field is going well, however the other record fields don't return any value after all tasks finish their work. I had help from Dalija in another question that operates only on the array and it worked, but now I'm having trouble with other fields.

This is my code :

```
program ProjectTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Threading;

type
  myrec = record
    vet: array of integer;
    total: integer;
    average: integer;
  end;

// (1) ===> here is the major procedure that populates the dyn. array and
// calculates other two fields  :  myrec.total  and myrec.avg

procedure ProcA(const pin, pfin: integer; var Prec: myrec);
var
  vind: integer;
begin
  for vind := pin to pfin do
    begin
      Prec.vet[vind] := vind * 10;
      Prec.total := Prec.total + Prec.vet[vind];        // sum all array values
    end;
  Prec.average := Trunc(Prec.total / Length(Prec.vet)); // calculates the average

end;

// (2)  Here iTask is created and calls ProcA

function CreateTask(first, last: integer; var Pmyrec: myrec): ITask;

var
  mylocalrec: myrec;

begin
  mylocalrec := Pmyrec;
  Result := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      ProcA(first, last, mylocalrec)
    end);
end;

procedure Test;
var
  Recarray: myrec;
  Ptasks: array of ITask;
  vind, indtask, vslice: integer;
  vfirst, vlast, vthreads, vsize: integer;
begin

  vthreads := 4;
  vsize := 16;

  SetLength(Ptasks, vthreads);
  SetLength(Recarray.vet, vsize);

  // Initialize the array , just to check after iTask execution
  for vind := low(Recarray.vet) to high(Recarray.vet) do
    Recarray.vet[vind] := -33;

  // initialize the sum and average field just to check after iTask execution
  Recarray.total := -1;
  Recarray.average := -2;

  // portion of array to scan for each iTask
  vslice := Length(Recarray.vet) div vthreads;

  for indtask := low(Ptasks) to high(Ptasks) do
    begin
      vfirst := indtask * vslice;
      vlast := (indtask + 1) * vslice - 1;

      if (Length(Recarray.vet) mod vthreads <> 0) and (indtask = high(Ptasks)) then vlast := high(Recarray.vet);

      Ptasks[indtask] := CreateTask(vfirst, vlast, Recarray);
    end;

  // Starting all Tasks
  for indtask := low(Ptasks) to high(Ptasks) do
    Ptasks[indtask].Start;

  // Waits for all Tasks been concluded
  TTask.WaitForAll(Ptasks);

  // (3) Here it is listed the array contents and it is ok
  for vind := low(Recarray.vet) to high(Recarray.vet) do
      Writeln(' Array position  : ' + Format('%.3d', [vind]) + '   content  : ' + Recarray.vet[vind].tostring);

  Writeln(' =========================================================');

// (4) Here is is listed fields recarray.total and recarray.avg and they were not
// processed inside the iTask .    I expected to see the computed values for those fields

  Writeln(' Array sum   : ' + Format('%.0d', [Recarray.total]) + '    Array average   : ' + Format('%5.2n', [Recarray.average * 1.0]));

end;

begin
  Test;
  Readln;
end.
```

And the output is :

```
 Array position  : 000   content  : 0
 Array position  : 001   content  : 10
 Array position  : 002   content  : 20
 Array position  : 003   content  : 30
 Array position  : 004   content  : 40
 Array position  : 005   content  : 50
 Array position  : 006   content  : 60
 Array position  : 007   content  : 70
 Array position  : 008   content  : 80
 Array position  : 009   content  : 90
 Array position  : 010   content  : 100
 Array position  : 011   content  : 110
 Array position  : 012   content  : 120
 Array position  : 013   content  : 130
 Array position  : 014   content  : 140
 Array position  : 015   content  : 150
 =========================================================
 Array sum   : -1    Array average   : -2,00
```

The problem is: after running all the iTasks, only the dynamic array field `recarray.vet` contain correct values. The fields `recarray.total` and `recarray.average` still contain their initial values as before the iTask have run.

How to correctly update values in those fields, so they will contain correct values after tasks finish running?

Comment: Try calculating your Average and Total after WaitForAll, otherwise you are going to need to deal with collision and implement TInterlocked for those values. That said I am not sure how you are getting any value back at all must be compiler magic. Also no one can run your demo, so no one can give you tested advice.

Comment: @Freds, I think the code I posted is completed , I can compile and run it normally, and I get the results in the  myrec.vet dynamic array field.  Did you try that ?   Why did you say no one can run my demo ?

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @FredS,thsnk for the help.  I complemented the code, removed what was not necessary and added comments in the key parts related to the problem and what was expected as a result.  I hope now anyone can reproduce it and give some advices.  Thanks.

Comment: Well you failed, I see "{$R *.dfm}" and no DFM file. But really this should be a simple console app. Then all it takes is pasting it into notepad and changing the extension to DPR..

Comment: @FredS, if I understood well, should I copy and paste the .dfm code into this question?

Comment: @JRG, a console application does not need a visual form. But consider rethinking your strategy here. As FredS said in his first comment, total and average fields are shared in the same record for all threads. This will only cause agony when preventing the threads from operating at the same fields simultaneously. Better to let the threads return those values separately, and handle the summary when threads end.

Comment: @LU RD, thanks for the explanations.  I got the point  regarding threads trying to update the same field at same time.  I'll think another way to get these values calculated !   Thank you all for the help and directions !

Comment: I have edited your question to simplify your code and make proper [mcve]. for testing such code you don't need to involve forms. You can create simple console application and everything will be inside single file.

Comment: Like I commented in your previous question, records are value types and you cannot handle them the way you can handle dynamic arrays. Also you have threading issue while calculating your integer fields because your tasks run in parallel.

Comment: @Dalija, great help in edit my code, thanks a lot!  I'll study more about console application to make my questions here more clear and easier for getting help.   I'll wait for your comments too !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it seems that your code has only one problem - how to populate integer fields in a record with tasks - when you solve that one you will have another issue - reading and writing same memory location from multiple threads.

**1. How to populate integer fields in a record?**

Records are value types and dynamic arrays are reference types. That is the reason why your code can update values in array but it cannot update values in record.

Let's see what is happening here.

```
function CreateTask(first, last: integer; var pmyrec: myrec): ITask;
var
  mylocalrec: myrec;
begin
  mylocalrec := pmyrec;
```

Since `mylocalrec` and `pmyrec` are records (value types) their content will occupy two different memory locations. Above assignment will copy the **content** of the `pmyrec` into `mylocalrec`.

That will be equivalent of following:

```
mylocalrec.vet := pmyrec.vet;
mylocalrec.total := pmyrec.total;
mylocalrec.average := pmyrec.average;
```

Since `total` and `average` are also value types their content will be copied and from this point on any change to either of those integer fields in `mylocalrec` will not have any effect to the original `pmyrec`. This is why your code is failing.

Why assigning dynamic array field `vet` from `pmyrec` to `mylocalrec` works?

Because dynamic arrays are reference types - assignment from one variable to another only copies value of the reference (pointer) and not the actual content. Both `vet` variables will point to the same array you have allocated before you started running your tasks.

To solve above issue you have to pass some reference type instead of value type. The simplest thing is declaring record pointer type and passing that one.

```
type
  myrec = record
    vet: array of integer;
    total: integer;
    average: integer;
  end;

  pmyrec = ^myrec;


function CreateTask(first, last: integer; rec: pmyrec): ITask;
var
  mylocalrec: pmyrec;
begin
  mylocalrec := rec;
  Result := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      ProcA(first, last, mylocalrec^)
    end);
end;

...
Ptasks[indtask] := CreateTask(vfirst, vlast, @Recarray);
```

**2. How to solve threading issue?**

After you have solved original issue you will experience threading issue. Reading and writing same memory location from multiple threads is not safe. Results you will get may be incorrect. While you can run your code thousand times and all values might be correct, sooner or later you will run into situation where they will not.

Populating dynamic array is safe in your case, because each thread operates on distinct part of the array and the array is not reallocated (its size is not changed) while your tasks run. That part of your code is thread safe.

Calculating `total` and `average` is not thread safe.

You have to synchronize such code with the main thread - in that case all reading and writing will be done from main thread and you will get correct results. Or you have to run such code after all tasks are finished. Whichever is more suitable for particular case.

```
procedure ProcA(const pin, pfin: integer; prec: pmyrec);
var
  vind: integer;
  total: integer;
begin
  total := 0;
  for vind := pin to pfin do
    begin
      prec.vet[vind] := vind * 10;
      total := total + prec.vet[vind];        // sum all array values
    end;

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      prec.total := prec.total + total;
      prec.average := Trunc(prec.total / Length(prec.vet)); // calculates the average
    end);
end;
```

However, synchronizing with the main thread within the tasks will cause the deadlock with `TTask.WaitForAll` method that also runs from the main thread in your case. To solve that part, you also have to run whole `Test` method from another thread.

```
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      Test;
    end);
```

And when we put all those parts together, complete code would be:

```
program ProjectTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Threading;

type
  myrec = record
    vet: array of integer;
    total: integer;
    average: integer;
  end;

  pmyrec = ^myrec;

// (1) ===> here is the major procedure that populates the dyn. array and
// calculates other two fields  :  myrec.total  and myrec.avg

procedure ProcA(const pin, pfin: integer; prec: pmyrec);
var
  vind: integer;
  total: integer;
begin
  total := 0;
  for vind := pin to pfin do
    begin
      prec.vet[vind] := vind * 10;
      total := total + prec.vet[vind];        // sum all array values
    end;

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      prec.total := prec.total + total;
      prec.average := Trunc(prec.total / Length(prec.vet)); // calculates the average
    end);
end;

// (2)  Here iTask is created and calls ProcA

function CreateTask(first, last: integer; rec: pmyrec): ITask;
var
  mylocalrec: pmyrec;
begin
  mylocalrec := rec;
  Result := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      ProcA(first, last, mylocalrec);
    end);
end;

procedure Test;
var
  Recarray: myrec;
  Ptasks: array of ITask;
  vind, indtask, vslice: integer;
  vfirst, vlast, vthreads, vsize: integer;
begin

  vthreads := 4;
  vsize := 16;

  SetLength(Ptasks, vthreads);
  SetLength(Recarray.vet, vsize);

  // Initialize the array , just to check after iTask execution
  for vind := low(Recarray.vet) to high(Recarray.vet) do
    Recarray.vet[vind] := -33;

  // initialize the sum and average field just to check after iTask execution
  Recarray.total := -1;
  Recarray.average := -2;

  // portion of array to scan for each iTask
  vslice := Length(Recarray.vet) div vthreads;

  for indtask := low(Ptasks) to high(Ptasks) do
    begin
      vfirst := indtask * vslice;
      vlast := (indtask + 1) * vslice - 1;

      if (Length(Recarray.vet) mod vthreads <> 0) and (indtask = high(Ptasks)) then vlast := high(Recarray.vet);

      Ptasks[indtask] := CreateTask(vfirst, vlast, @Recarray);
    end;

  // Starting all Tasks
  for indtask := low(Ptasks) to high(Ptasks) do
    Ptasks[indtask].Start;

  // Waits for all Tasks been concluded
  TTask.WaitForAll(Ptasks);

  // (3) Here it is listed the array contents and it is ok
  for vind := low(Recarray.vet) to high(Recarray.vet) do
      Writeln(' Array position  : ' + Format('%.3d', [vind]) + '   content  : ' + Recarray.vet[vind].tostring);

  Writeln(' =========================================================');

// (4) Here is is listed fields recarray.total and recarray.avg and they were not
// processed inside the iTask .    I expected to see the computed values for those fields

  Writeln(' Array sum   : ' + Format('%.0d', [Recarray.total]) + '    Array average   : ' + Format('%5.2n', [Recarray.average * 1.0]));

end;

begin
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      Test;
    end);
end.
```

Comment: Note to @JRG. Even though this answer demonstrates how to do this correctly (+1), your strategy to split the calculation into several threads has a price. It complicates code and is about 5000 times slower than a straight calculation in a single thread.

Comment: @Dalija, besides to help me solve this issue, I think your major contribution was to share such valuable and precise concepts presented  in a clear, precise and didactical way, thanks so much !   I understood it all. To use pointer for the myrec was a key part that I'd take a long time to find by myself !  I will count on you for my next questions.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: @LU RD, fully agree with you, thanks for the alert  !  I have to take care to avoid code complexity and risks.  Regarding the speed , I'll test it carefully once my major goal when splitting the  array processing into tasks was improve the speed, not the contrary ! Conceptually speaking it is expected that code splitted into threads  would be faster.  Why did you say it is about 5000 slower ?   In real application my dynamic array will have between  20.000 to 40.000 records.  I appreciate your comment on this.

Comment: @JRG, premature optimization can lead to unnecessary complex code. Only optimize if there is a problem with performance in your real application, and then use instrument analysis tools to find bottlenecks.

Comment: @JRG, My test called the `Test` routine (without printout overhead) 100000 times with and without the splitting into threads, which gave that big speed difference. If I called only once, but with a `vet` size of 1.6 million elements, the single thread still was 6 times faster.

Comment: @LU RD, I'll evaluate this performace issue carefully.  My  application has a dynamic array of record quite different of the code I posted. I really had the main issue of parameters "values vs reference  in iTask" and I could solve it with the answers proposed here, BUT regarding performance , when I splitted the array processing into 4 threads I could reduce the speed by 60% in average, which I consider a good rate. Unfortunatelly I'm facing a new issue now : memory leaks. Memory is increasing and when  all 4 iTasks finish it does not return to normal level. I'll need  your help again soon.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 minute after dinner digestive :)

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.SyncObjs,
  System.Threading;

type
  Pmyrec = ^Tmyrec;
  Tmyrec = record
    vet: array of integer;
    total: integer;
    average: integer;
  end;

// (1) ===> here is the major procedure that populates the dyn. array and
// calculates other two fields  :  Tmyrec.total  and Tmyrec.avg

procedure ProcA(const pin, pfin: integer; const Prec: Pmyrec);
var
  vind: integer;
begin
  for vind := pin to pfin do
    begin
      Prec.vet[vind] := vind * 10;
      TInterlocked.Add(Prec.total, Prec.vet[vind]);     // sum all array values
    end;
end;

// (2)  Here iTask is created and calls ProcA

function CreateTask(first, last: integer; const Pmyrec: Pmyrec): ITask;
begin
  Result := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      ProcA(first, last, Pmyrec)
    end);
end;

procedure Test;
var
  Recarray: Tmyrec;
  Ptasks: array of ITask;
  vind, indtask, vslice: integer;
  vfirst, vlast, vthreads, vsize: integer;
begin

  vthreads := 4;
  vsize := 16;

  SetLength(Ptasks, vthreads);
  SetLength(Recarray.vet, vsize);

  // Initialize the array , just to check after iTask execution
  for vind := low(Recarray.vet) to high(Recarray.vet) do
    Recarray.vet[vind] := -33;

  // initialize the sum and average field just to check after iTask execution
  Recarray.total := -1;
  Recarray.average := -2;

  // portion of array to scan for each iTask
  vslice := Length(Recarray.vet) div vthreads;

  for indtask := low(Ptasks) to high(Ptasks) do
    begin
      vfirst := indtask * vslice;
      vlast := (indtask + 1) * vslice - 1;

      if (Length(Recarray.vet) mod vthreads <> 0) and (indtask = high(Ptasks)) then vlast := high(Recarray.vet);

      Ptasks[indtask] := CreateTask(vfirst, vlast, @Recarray);
    end;

  // Starting all Tasks
  for indtask := low(Ptasks) to high(Ptasks) do
    Ptasks[indtask].Start;

  // Waits for all Tasks been concluded
  TTask.WaitForAll(Ptasks);
  Recarray.average := Trunc(Recarray.total / Length(Recarray.vet)); // calculates the average


  // (3) Here it is listed the array contents and it is ok
  for vind := low(Recarray.vet) to high(Recarray.vet) do
      Writeln(' Array position  : ' + Format('%.3d', [vind]) + '   content  : ' + Recarray.vet[vind].tostring);

  Writeln(' =========================================================');

// (4) Here is is listed fields recarray.total and recarray.avg and they were not
// processed inside the iTask .    I expected to see the computed values for those fields

  Writeln(' Array sum   : ' + Format('%.0d', [Recarray.total]) + '    Array average   : ' + Format('%5.2n', [Recarray.average * 1.0]));

end;

begin
  Test;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! Great point the TInterlocked.Add .  I studied it and seems to be the right choice for the total !  About  to calculate average after run all tasks , it makes sense !   I'll improve the code with your  tips too !   Thank you !